# Is there a way to make a custom XML property required in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am writing a custom *Layout* Object, and I would like to enforce that the developer specifies a particular XML attribute. An example of what I mean is how for all `View` Objects, the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes are required.

From what I can tell from doing some research is that there appears to be a custom `TypedArray` method called [getLayoutDimension(int, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getLayoutDimension%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) that handles this enforcement by expecting a dimension, and providing the given string as part of an error message if that dimension is not valid. Ideally, I can do this sort of thing other types too, such as enums. Does this feature exist in the Android SDK?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before and I implemented it in the ctor of the custom layout. I'd query for something and if its not available throw a RuntimeException.

```
final TypedArray attributeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.styledTextView);
final String typeface = (attributeArray != null)
                                ? attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.styledTextView_font)
                                : null;

if(typeface == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("must provide foo:typeface attribute for this view.");
```

That worked for what we needed to accomplish.

Comment: Does the error then show up in the XML editor? I want to avoid crashing the app if I can.

Comment: Not that I know of. Its a development problem, so IMO it should bomb if its not available.